# Còmo insertar la accion IF en una tabla?

Tags: php, sql

> este debe arrojar un mensaje, lo que pido es que este mensaje aparezca
>   en la tabla que inserte

```
$consull = ("SELECT cantidad * FROM evalua.preguntas_contestadas WHERE 
nocontrol='$nocontrol' AND doc_idcontrol='$nocontrol'");
$evalua = mysql_query($consull);

//consultar el numero de preguntas totales 
$totall = ("SELECT COUNT(idpregunta) AS preguntas_totales FROM 
evalua.pregunta");
$twoconsull = mysql_query($totall);

echo '<center><br>';
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<td>Evaluacion</td>';

if ($evalua >= $twoconsull) {
    echo "Completado";
}
else {
    echo "No Completado";
}

echo "<tr><td>"[""]"</td>"**
```

Comment: creo que en el primer select tiene un error con ese *, por otro lado que deseas hacer con el if ?

Comment: con las consultas debe proporcionar una cantidad x, el if solo muestra los mensajes... quiero que esos mensajes aparezcan en la tabla que cree...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun la secuencia que llebas esto es lo que necesitas...

```
$consull = ("SELECT cantidad * FROM evalua.preguntas_contestadas WHERE nocontrol='$nocontrol' AND doc_idcontrol='$nocontrol'");
$evalua = mysql_query($consull);

//consultar el numero de preguntas totales 
$totall = ("SELECT COUNT(idpregunta) AS preguntas_totales FROM evalua.pregunta");
$twoconsull = mysql_query($totall);

echo '<center><br>';
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr><th>Evaluacion</th></td>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
if ($evalua >= $twoconsull) {
    echo "<tr><td>Completado</tr></td>";
}
else {
    echo "<tr><td>No Completado</tr></td>";
}

echo "</tbody>"
```

pruebalo y me cuentas, espero te sirva y la marques... ReNiceCode...

Comment: ok, lo intentare con este código. Gracias !!!

Comment: ok, me cuentas como te fue..